# Random unit test fail during code coverage generation in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

OK I'm having a problem with code coverage generation in VS2013 that I don't think there is a solution anywhere on the Internet

I'm having a test suite of 900+ unit tests for my project that are all passed if run in VS2010

The test suite works fine (100% pass) if I run them in VS2013 from the menu Test > Run > All Tests

However, if I want to generate code coverage in VS2013 from the menu Test > Analyze Code Coverage > All Tests, many of the tests (500+ of them) will fail with no particular reason at all

Test run detail window contains no useful information as it cannot point out why the test failed (screenshot below)

[image: test fail with no useful information]

**Notes**:

- The test will pass if I re-run that particular test, or run all the tests from the menu Test > Run > All Tests
- This problem occurs randomly on my machine and some others, while for the rest of the team, code coverage generation works fine (100% test pass)
- This problem never occurs in VS2010

**Edit**

Adding the code for BoreholeRepositoryTest at line 98

It's just the starting point of a test

[image]

Comment: You probably have a race condition or coupling issue in your tests that only presents itself under some circumstances. It's impossible to say more than that. Are these true unit tests (e.g. they run in total isolation), or are there integration tests mixed in?

Comment: Hi Daniel, those are unit tests only, no integration test. Tests are all independent (they can be run in any order under vs2010 and still pass)

Comment: Can you post the code for BoreholeRepositoryTest.cs (particularly interested for line 98)? @DanielMann is very likely correct in that there is some race condition that is contributing to this. (e.g., a resource might be shared though no one is expecting it to be shared)

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Can you show the entire test please? :-) (Posting the code in a code block would be preferable to a screenshot, too.)

Comment: To clarify: only the code for the `GetBoreholeWithDescriptiveLocation` test is necessary - not the entire file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem

I notice that QTAgent32_40.exe randomly crashes during the test running process, resulting tests that are yet to be executed to fail

A bit of research afterwards reveals the root of my problem

I was using xxx.testsettings file to control code coverage result. It appears that VS2013 uses a newer test framework, which does not play well with testsettings file. If you use a .testsettings file, the MSTest test framework will be used to run your tests. This runs more slowly and does not allow you to run tests from third-party test frameworks.

**So the solution is:** get rid of the good old testsettings file and create a new runsettings file as advised by Microsoft.

Case solved :)